# estoy intentando hacer un query geoespacial pero no me funciona

Tags: nodejs, google-maps

este es mi query en postman `{{URL}}/api/v1/tours/tours-within/233/center/34.111745,-118.113491/unit/mi` y este es mi codigo en Node.js

en las rutas

```js
router
  .route('/tours-within/:distance/center/:latlng/unit/:unit')
  .get(tourController.getToursWithin);
```

en el controlador

```js
exports.getToursWithin = (req, res, next) => {
  const { distance, latlng, unit } = req.params;
  const { lat, lng } = latlng.split(',');

  if (!lat || !lng) {
    next(
      new AppError(
        'Please provide latitude and longitude in the format lat,lng',
        400
      )
    );
  }

  console.log(distance, lat, lng, unit);

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success'
  });
};
```

soy de Paraguay y estoy probando una latitud y longitud de Los Angeles pero no se si la distancia que pase esta mal ¿como puedo saber que distancia poner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en esta línea

```
 const { lat, lng } = latlng.split(',');
```

Cuando haces un  `.split`, lo haces sobre una cadena de texto, eg: `"123,456"` y este te devuelve un arreglo.

```
["123", "456"]
```

Con la operación que tienes a la izquierda en el código original estás haciendo un **Object destructuring**, pero en verdad deberías hacer un **Array destructuring**, con lo que deberías tener tu código así:

```
const [ lat, lng ] = latlng.split(',');
```

Comment: Si tienes razon!! estoy usando un arreglo, claro lo siento no me abre dado cuenta y puse llaves en vez de corchetes, gracias, ya te vote mannita arriba.